# How do I divide a dataset into training and test sets using Weka?

Tags: java, csv, weka

I want to divide a million-record dataset in CSV format into 80% for training and 20% for testing. How can I code for this using Java or Weka library?

Comment: Why don't you just do it randomly by using standard random number generators?

Comment: As JS Meier said: read file line by line and decide if you want to put such line into TEST.csv file or TRAIN.csv file. There are hundreds of examples on the web how to handle text files.

Comment: I can understand that you said. But friends if i will change and update data set i need to manual process for each data set. Actually i want use this one for machine learning  so there is need to proper random data set processing and your idea will increase the cost of process. If you can understand what i am  saying you then give me another idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Java with the Weka library using a filter called [StratifiedRemoveFolds](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/instance/StratifiedRemoveFolds.html)

```
// Load data  
DataSource source = new DataSource("/some/where/data.csv");
Instances data = source.getDataSet();

// Set class to last attribute
if (data.classIndex() == -1)
    data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

// use StratifiedRemoveFolds to randomly split the data  
StratifiedRemoveFolds filter = new StratifiedRemoveFolds();

// set options for creating the subset of data
String[] options = new String[6];

options[0] = "-N";                 // indicate we want to set the number of folds                        
options[1] = Integer.toString(5);  // split the data into five random folds
options[2] = "-F";                 // indicate we want to select a specific fold
options[3] = Integer.toString(1);  // select the first fold
options[4] = "-S";                 // indicate we want to set the random seed
options[5] = Integer.toString(1);  // set the random seed to 1

filter.setOptions(options);        // set the filter options
filter.setInputFormat(data);       // prepare the filter for the data format    
filter.setInvertSelection(false);  // do not invert the selection

// apply filter for test data here
Instances test = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);

//  prepare and apply filter for training data here
filter.setInvertSelection(true);     // invert the selection to get other data 
Instances train = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the methods provided by `Instances` First randomize your data

```
Random rand = new Random(seed);   // create seeded number generator
randData = new Instances(data);   // create copy of original data
randData.randomize(rand);         // randomize data with number generator
```

In case your data has a nominal class and you wanna perform stratified cross-validation:

```
randData.stratify(folds);
```

Now, normally you would want to do a cross-validation and do this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < folds; n++) {
    Instances train = randData.trainCV(folds, n);
    Instances test = randData.testCV(folds, n);

    // further processing, classification, etc.
    ...
}
```

(The source actually mentions that "the above code is used by the `weka.filters.supervised.instance.StratifiedRemoveFolds` filter")

But if you only want one set of 80/20 instances, then just do it once:

```
Instances train = randData.trainCV(folds, 0);
Instances test = randData.testCV(folds, 0);
```

[Source](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+(Java+approach))

Comment: @Sentry How does your for loop divide training and test sets? For example, if i want %90 of my data is training set, and %10 is test set, how one can create it?

Comment: The way I did it (use Weka's methods), the data is always divided so that (k-1)/k are training set and 1/k are test set. If you want to divide 90/10, you have to choose k=10. And if you don't want to have 10 different splits, use the method described above and not use a for-loop.